# Does IIS 8.5 application pool suspension trigger the Application_End method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8, application-pool

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that needs to run certain tasks when its IIS application pool reaches its Idle Timeout period, before it is suspended.

My IIS settings dictate that the threads should not be terminated, but instead be suspended.

`Idle Timeout Action: Suspend`

I know that termination will trigger the HttpApplication.Application_End method, but I cant find documentation on whether suspension will do the same.

Comment: can you make a test ?

Comment: I could :) But I LOVE documentation as it comes with a lot of details, edge cases etc. that a test might not expose. Also hoping to find out what other method(s) get fired during a `Suspend`